# Appium: Button disappears before test has time to click it (iOS)

Tags: javascript, appium, appium-ios

Quite new to looking into Appium on iOS at the moment using Mocha & JavaScript, I've hit a stumbling block with it though. Our app features video playback & once you go full screen, the only way to exit full screen is to press anywhere on the screen then hit the 'Done' button that appears.

The problem I'm having is that the 'Done' button appears on the screen for roughly 3.5 seconds & by the time the test attempts to click it, it has already disappeared from view again.

Is there anyway round this, by either reducing the default delay between clicks or performing 2 clicks/taps in quick succession?

Currently my test works if I manually press the screen again as soon as the 'Done' button first disappears from view but I can't seem to automate the process.

My code currently looks like this:

```js
//Opens the video in full screen
.elementByXPath("//*[@name='Live']").click()
.elementByXPath("//UIAWindow[1]/UIAElement[1]").click()

//Delay of 5 seconds to allow video to play
.sleep(5000)

//Press the video screen to get 'Done' button to appear
.elementByXPath("//UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]").click()

//Attempt to click 'Done' button; it always disappears before it can be clicked
.elementByXPath("//*[@name='Done']").click()
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I say, I'm quite new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is :

You are trying to find the "Done" button after tapping anywhere on the screen and appium takes some seconds to find the element.

**Solution:**

If the location of "Done" button which appears every time is same then you can perform click action using X and Y co-ordinates instead of finding the actual element.

Find the X and Y co-ordinates of "Done" button manually (One time process).

and then click on X and Y co-ordinates.

```
driver.tap(numberOfFingers,X-co-ordinate,Y-co-ordinate,durationInMilliseconds)
```

e.g. `driver.tap(1,200,300,1000)`

I hope this helps :)